# View or print a JavaDoc in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: java, jupyter, jshell

I'm using Jupyter Notebook with the [IJava](https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava) Java kernel via  for learning and testing code. IJava utilises jshell. Is there a way to print the JavaDoc for a specific class or function?

I can print Python docstrings in a Jupyter notebook in several ways, using the `help()`, `func.__doc__` or `?func()` methods.

[image: python example]

Is there a way to do this in Java?

Something like :

[image: java_desired_result]

Comment: At the time of writing this, jshell's javadoc support is very limited. It only supports javadocs from the standard library (anything in your jdk installation's `src.zip`). See also [IJava's github issue related to this](https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava/issues/8#issuecomment-443480955). I've avoided a `help` function (IJava would use a magic) like python's specifically for this reason, as it's usage would be very limited as well. To summarize, there is nothing in IJava that does this yet. You can `shift`-`tab` to get signatures and javadocs on standard library classes/methods.

Answer (score -2):

I'm using the very same java kernel from https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava

and the  prints are working fine. plz look at my screenshot below:

[image]

[screenshot-of-Java-Kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSVkT.png)

Verify your Java version. I'm using JDK-11.0.1 downloaded form here:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk11-downloads-5066655.html

Comment: The question is not about printing in general but printing a **javadoc**. I've left a comment on the original question about this not being supported at the moment.